# AVL Tree vs Balanced Tree

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures

*AVL tree* is a well known internal memory data structure whereas *Balanced tree* is known external memory data structure.
**Why can't we use Balanced trees for internal memory also?**

Comment: AVL trees are also balanced. And obviously anything that works in external memory still works in internal memory.

Comment: You are obviously right, they can be used but why balanced trees are not preferred for CPU computations in internal memory as AVL trees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You very much *can* have balanced trees in internal memory. An AVL tree is simply one type of balanced tree and there are others as well, such as red-black and 2-3-4 trees.

So, I'm not sure *where* you got the idea balanced trees couldn't exist in internal memory but I'd be rethinking that if I were you.

And, in fact, you could put an AVL tree on disk as well if you were so inclined.

---

I suspect, based on your comments, that what you *may* be thinking of is a BTree which is like a binary tree but each node can hold more than one value and have more than two children, such as:

```
root node -,
           |
           V
 +------+------+------+
 | Val1 | Val2 | val3 |
 +------+------+------+
/       |      |      \
<other nodes down here>
```

That's different to the more general term 'balanced tree' and they're often used in disk situations as you tend to want to read/write entire blocks/clusters/sectors at a time.

So, if you can fit ten values into a disk block, it's more efficient to use a BTree (whereas memory does not have a concept of block size so it can be preferable to use a simpler algorithm - BTrees have to combine both tree search to find a node and linear/binary search to locate the value *in* the node).

But, while BTrees can be a *type* of balanced tree, it's again only *one* type.

Comment: If we use AVL or RB tree in database for indexing then obviously, it would be wasting a lot more space than B-Tree. For this reason only, we say B-tree have a good I/O cost factor as it contains more than many key in node or disk block. 
**Now for CPU computations, do they have any difference in performance?**

Comment: @anand011090, yes. For a BTree (which is only *one* type of balanced tree), it takes more work because you have to use tree algorithms to find the node a value is in, then either a linear search or binary chop to locate the value *within* the node.